# Filter django data using Q

Tags: python, django, django-q

```
category = request.GET.get('cat')
from_p = request.GET.get('from')
to_p = request.GET.get('to')

q = Q()
if category:
    q |= Q(category=category)
if from_p:
    q |= Q(price__gt=from_p)
if to_p:
    q |= Q(price__lt=to_p)

s = Sample.objects.filter(q)
```

> www.example.com/?cat=0&from=300&to=600

If first is `category` -  `from_p` and `to_p` criterion not working. How to fix it?
It work only for one criterion. I need if user set (for example) `category` and `from_p` search by these criterion.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Here it is:

```
q_cat = Q(category=category) if category else Q()
q_from = Q(price__gt=from_p) if from_p else Q()
q_to = Q(price__lt=to_p) if to_p else Q()

q = q_cat | ( q_from  & q_to )

s = Sample.objects.filter(  q )
```

Comment: Thanks, but still if I set `category` and `to_p` this code filter only by `category` (because it is the first)

Comment: This is an `OR` operator! Not an `AND` it filters by first `OR` second.

Comment: I know. `AND` operator also is not good(it filters only if every field is set). How to change it?

Comment: a little dirty, try it. I'm not happy about results, perhaps someone post a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value